# Flash and World Map

Tags: flash-cs4

Is there a control available that allows us to include a world map and define the regions in the map? Appreciate any inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is quite what you're looking for, but Google has some APIs which allow you to do this:

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html
http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/intensitymap.html

The Geo Map is a flash movie, and the Intensity Map is an image. I'm not too familiar with Flash, but I think you can use the APIs playground to [create a Geo Map](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_map) or [create an Intensity Map](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#intensity_map) and then inspect the element in Firebug or similar to get the url, and pass it into [loadMovie()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000573.html).

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Can we do this in Flash? The above examples are in HTML.